# Unity Webgl game never finishes loading.Browser tab freezes

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I'm developing a quiz game and want it to run on browsers.So far the game only loads to about 90% of the progress bar, then the tab freezes. A browser warning shows up at the top saying that something is making the page slow. This happens both when the game is run locally or from a server. 
The PC works fine and I wasn't able to find the problem so far. I tried playing wwith the build player configs and reducing all textre max sizes (solved the problem in this post https://forum.unity.com/threads/webgl-stuck-at-90-loading.532707/).

The last lines shown on the console before the load freezing are the json files readings. So I think it might have something to do with them. 
If anyone has any idea it would be a great help.

Comment: You can run it in debug mode locally and have it profiled and so on to see whats going on.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm new with web builds and can't seem to find out how to run it in debug mode. How exactly do I do it?

Comment: Then have a read of the unity documentation here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-debugging.html

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that WebAssembly streaming is disabled in the player settings, that 100% causes webgl to get stuck at 90% loading.